# Tensorflow is unable to use all visible GPUs

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a cluster with 8 GPUs and I would like to run a python script on it. I know the script is fine, because it runs on a single GPU cluster. However, when trying to run on this 8 gpu cluster, I am receiving the following error message:

```
to use: AVX2 AVX512F FMA
2018-03-29 18:42:51.800702: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1212] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:3d:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.76GiB
2018-03-29 18:42:52.347624: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1212] Found device 1 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:3e:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.76GiB
2018-03-29 18:42:52.882324: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1212] Found device 2 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:60:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.76GiB
2018-03-29 18:42:53.591909: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1212] Found device 3 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:61:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.76GiB
2018-03-29 18:42:54.149671: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1212] Found device 4 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:b1:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.76GiB
2018-03-29 18:42:54.715701: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1212] Found device 5 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:b2:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.76GiB
2018-03-29 18:42:55.286011: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1212] Found device 6 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:da:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.76GiB
2018-03-29 18:42:55.874676: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1212] Found device 7 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:db:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.76GiB
2018-03-29 18:42:55.929779: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1227] Device peer to peer matrix
2018-03-29 18:42:55.930506: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1233] DMA: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2018-03-29 18:42:55.930524: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1243] 0:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2018-03-29 18:42:55.930533: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1243] 1:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2018-03-29 18:42:55.930542: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1243] 2:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2018-03-29 18:42:55.930550: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1243] 3:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2018-03-29 18:42:55.930559: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1243] 4:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2018-03-29 18:42:55.930567: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1243] 5:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2018-03-29 18:42:55.930576: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1243] 6:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2018-03-29 18:42:55.930586: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1243] 7:   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
2018-03-29 18:42:55.930741: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1312] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
2018-03-29 18:43:00.106517: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10415 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:3d:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-03-29 18:43:00.572522: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 10415 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:3e:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-03-29 18:43:01.039866: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:2 with 10415 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 2, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:60:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-03-29 18:43:01.512332: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:3 with 10415 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 3, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:61:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-03-29 18:43:02.036327: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:4 with 10415 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 4, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:b1:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-03-29 18:43:02.679167: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:5 with 10415 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 5, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:b2:00.0, compute capability: 6.1) 
killed
```

It just blandly says `killed` and I'm not sure why this error occurs. I tried specifying just two GPUs using the following command:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 python3 my_script.py
```

But that printed the following error:

```
Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 10415 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:3e:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-03-29 18:47:46.208490: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:378] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7102 (compatibility version 7100) but source was compiled with 7004 (compatibility version 7000).  If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library to match.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime matches a compatible version specified during compile configuration.
2018-03-29 18:47:46.210296: F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:717] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo<T>(), &algorithms)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I install tensorflow-gpu using the following commands:

```
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu 
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

Could this potentially have anything to do with "activating" tensorflow? I'm not sure how to do this on the cluster, since I'm not sure if this considered virtual environment

Comment: What version of the CuDNN libraries do you have installed?

Comment: I'm not sure, how do I check this?

Comment: Seems like you have installed cuDNN 7.1. Tensorflow's prebuilt binaries are compiled against cuDnn 7.0, so you will have to downgrade or (not 100% sure if it will work) compile from source against 7.1.

Comment: I see, and how exactly do I downgrade?

Comment: Google for the cudnn download, it's just 3 or 4 files that it's adding. They are pointed to by the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH, so check that it's set correctly.

Comment: Also, on the NVIDIA website, it says that there is Tensorflow support for 7.1. So, would this really be the problem? https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn

Comment: Yeah, not sure really, that's why you've gotten comments rather than answers along these lines. It's a reasonable direction to take in troubleshooting though. I'd install CUDA 9.0 (9.1 is not supported yet) and maybe cuDNN 7.0 and 7.1 into separate folders in your home directory. Then edit your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the right one and test it, then report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to downgrade your cuDNN version.
I solved this problem with **7.0.5**.

[Download cuDNN v7.0.5 (Dec 5, 2017), for CUDA 9.0](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download)

Download .tar file from **cuDNN v7.0.5 Library for Linux**.

(on Ubuntu 16)

Before, you need to remove all cuDNN files:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
```

Now extract your new cuDNN from the file downloaded:

```
tar xvzf cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz
```

Move new files to **cuda** directory:

```
sudo cp -P cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include    
sudo cp -P cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

Set permissions to this files:

```
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
```

Comment: The last command does work. I get "not a directory error" for the chmod command. For some reason, the include directory is being treated as a directory. Is that normal?